# How to insert color name with tag name in rtconner/laravel-tagging

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a package named rtconner/laravel-tagging for tags and I want to insert tag colors with tag name, I already modified the table and added a column named color. Before the code was

```
$tag_name = 'test_tag';
$tags_name = \App\Task::with('tagged')->first();
$tags_name->tag($tag_name);
```

Now I want to do this

```
$tag_name = 'test_tag';
$color='red';
$tags_name = \App\Task::with('tagged')->first();
$tags_name->tag($tag_name,$color);
```

It's running but it making 2 rows in database table, one for tag name and other one for color name
I want to store this color in the same table name.

Answer (score 0):

I've modify a package named rtconner and published. Now it's working fine for me

to install the package run `composer require softtechnoes/laravel-tagging` from your composer. the package will be install and use it.
Here's the git repository link [Colorful tagging](https://github.com/softtechnoes/laravel-tagging)